# How to find eigenvalue of $adj(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\alpha$ is a characteristic root of a nonsingular matrix then eigenvalue of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is?
I know $\operatorname{adj}(A)=\operatorname{det}(A)A^{-1}$ and $\operatorname{det}(A-\alpha{I})=0$. How can I use these to get result?

Comment: Do you know the relation of $\operatorname{Det}(A)$ to the eigenvalues of A, and for that matter the reationship of the eigenvalues of $A$ to the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: @triatticus I know relation between $det(A)$ and eigen value .its product of eigen value. But I don't know relation between eigen value and $A^{-1}$. Can u tell me?

Comment: Take $(A - \lambda I)$ and multiply by the inverse of $A$ since it is nonsingular, $A^{-1} (A - \lambda I) = (A^{-1}A - \lambda A^{-1}) = (I - \lambda A^{-1}) = -\lambda (-\lambda^{-1}I + A^{-1}) = -\lambda (A^{-1} - \lambda^{-1} I) = 0$. Since $\lambda$ is a nonzero cosntant we divide it to the other side to obtain $(A^{-1} - \lambda^{-1}I)$, thus if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$

Comment: By the way I tend to use $\lambda$ when talking about eigenvalues, you can replace all the $\lambda$ with $\alpha$ if you want to.

Comment: Thanx triatticus for ur support. Now I got it